# IdentityServer3: combine manual credentials login with social option

Tags: authentication, owin, identityserver3, openid-connect, katana

I am using IdentityServer3 to handle user authentication in a asp mvc web site.

The login screen is hosted in a view in the application itself (not using the Identity Server implicit flow). I also offer a "Login with Google" option, which the user chooses by clicking a button on the login screen.

Any page which has [Authorize] should redirect an unauthenticated user to the login screen:

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
        });
    }
```

The Account controller outline is shown below. The 'Forms Authentication' scenario will work ([as described here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/288)).

The 'Login with Google' button works [as described here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2028) (skipping the ID server login page, going direct to Google) by specifying an 'acr_values' param.

**How should I deal with the callback from the OpenID Connect** after I log in with Google? I tried adding the [OpenId Connect middleware](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect) but it doesn't play well with the 'LoginPath' feature on Cookie Authentication: unauthenticated users are now redirected to the ID Server login screen not my local login screen.

I can't see anything in the [IdentityServer samples](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source) that addresses this scenario.

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        ViewBag.GoogleLogin = CreateLoginUrl("Google");

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel vm)
    {
        // Call IdentityServer here with credentials
        // Validate token and do the Owin Authentication SignIn
        // Redirect to 'ReturnUrl'

        // If errors:
        return View(vm);
    }

    public ActionResult Callback()
    {
        // What goes here??

        return new RedirectResult("/");
    }

    private string CreateLoginUrl(string provider)
    {
        var state = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
        var nonce = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");

        var request = new AuthorizeRequest(new Uri("https://localhost:44312/connect/authorize"));
        var startUrl = request.CreateAuthorizeUrl(
                    clientId: "mvc",
                    responseType: "id_token token",
                    scope: "openid profile roles sampleApi",
                    redirectUri: "https://localhost:44319/Account/Callback",
                    state: state,
                    acrValues: "idp:" + provider,
                    nonce: nonce);

        return startUrl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sidestepped the issue of conflicting authentication providers by using the Map IAppBuilder extension to only apply the Open Id Connect Middleware to a single endpoint. This way the Social login flow is handled entirely by middleware, and the authentication cookie is shared by both authentication providers.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
    });
    app.Map(new PathString("/Account/SocialLogin"), ctx =>
    {
        ctx.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(Options());
    });
}
```

And the AccountController bit:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        return View(new LoginViewModel { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel vm)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(vm);
        }

        // Call IdentityServer here with credentials
        TokenResponse token = await GetToken(vm.UserName, vm.Password);

        // Validate token and do the Owin Authentication SignIn
        // Redirect to 'ReturnUrl'

        await SignInAsync(token);

        return new RedirectResult(vm.ReturnUrl);
    }

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult SocialLogin(string returnUrl)
    {
        return new RedirectResult(returnUrl);
    }

    // Some helpers omitted
}
```